# Error comparing decimal values in vba

Tags: vba

I got the next code:

```
aux = 97.8000030517578

Select Case aux
Case aux < 100
    Debug.Print "Menor que 100"
Case aux >= 97 And aux < 100
    Debug.Print "Medio"
Case aux < 97
    Debug.Print "malo"
End Select
```

And it doesn't accomplish any condition in the select, so it doesn't print anything. Any idea, help?

Comment: You need to use the `Is` keyword when using this operators in a `Case` statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it work changing:

```
aux = 97.8000030517578
Select Case aux
        Case 99 to 100
            Debug.Print "Menor que 100"
        Case 97 to 98.999
            Debug.Print "Medio"
        Case aux < 97
            Debug.Print "malo"
    End Select
```

I don't know if there's other way.

Comment: You need to change `Case aux < 97` to `Case Is < 97` for your third test to be evaluated correctly. Nonetheless still good job for sorting out first two conditions. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is another way:

```
aux = 97.8000030517578
Select Case True
Case aux >= 99 And aux < 100: Debug.Print "Menor que 100"
Case aux >= 97 And aux < 99: Debug.Print "Medio"
Case aux < 97: Debug.Print "malo"
End Select
```

In your first attempt, you are not actually testing the `aux` but the statements.
So might as well select the case where that statement is `True`.

Comment: That is brilliant, I have never thought to use a case statement in this way.

Comment: @DanDonoghue AFAIK this is the only way to use a `Case` statement with the `And` or `Or` operators. Very handy tip if you understand the logic.